# How can we create an instance for Supplier as it is an Interface?

Tags: java, lambda, supplier

I am trying to understand Supplier interface. I understand that it can return an object if we invoke its get() method. However, in the following example:

```
public class SupplierExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Supplier<String> s = new Supplier<String>() {
            public String get() {
                return "test";
            }
        };

        System.out.println(s.get());
    }
}
```

I am not able to understand how we can instantiate an object (s in above exaple) from an interface. Please advise.

Comment: You instantiated an anonymous class that implements the Supplier interface.

Comment: Note that you can also use lambdas and method references to instantiate instances of interfaces like `Supplier`. An example: `Supplier<String> s = () -> "test";`, pretty compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet contains an anonymous class instance, which implements the `Supplier<String>` interface.

It implements the only method of that interface with:

```
public String get() {
    return "test";
}
```

which returns the `String` "test".

Therefore, `s.get()` returns the `String` "test".

Comment: Eran, it means it is an anonymous inner class syntax where we have to write Interface name after new operator?